# Inner join in server side data table with php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
//define index of column
    $columns = array( 
        0 =>'id',
        1 =>'employee_name', 
        2 => 'employee_salary',
        3 => 'employee_age'
        4 =>'employee_City', 
        5 => 'employee_State',
        6 => 'employee_Pin'
    );

    $where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";
    if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" ( employee_name LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $where .=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";

        $where .=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }
    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;
    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }
```

Help me please, I have 3 tables, all tables has a primary key as table_id how to get data from 3 tables using server side datatables how to implement join query in this code. Here employee_City, employee_State and employee_Pin are stored in second table. Employ personal details Stored in third table. How to join all tables?

Comment: Did you want to get data from single table` employee` .. For fetch record from  only one table .. Then  we answer in this way... But you want to get data from multiple tabels.. Please explain cleanly what you want.. or edit the question @sambhu

Comment: share three table's structure and proper output u need

Answer (score 0):

I have just take dummy name of table city , state , pincode ..

Try with this query :

```
$sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age, employee_City, employee_State, employee_Pin FROM employee LEFT JOIN city ON employee.cityID = city.id  LEFT JOIN state ON employee.stateID = state.id  LEFT JOIN pincode ON employee.pincodeid = pincode.id  ";

  if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $sql .=" WHERE ";
        $sql .=" ( employee_name LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $sql .=" OR employee_salary LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql .=" OR employee_age LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }
$sql.=" ORDER BY employee_name";
```

Comment: @Sambhu .. What issue happen .. Please provide me second table name which you want to join.

Comment: i want to search like this  [link](https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Answer (score 0):

These links will help you make join query:

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php